# How to pass a value into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a directive to insert a youtube player in my templates,

```
app.directive('youtube', function($window, youTubeApiService) {

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      videoid: "@"
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $rootScope) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;

      youTubeApiService.onReady(function() {
        player = setupPlayer(scope, element);
      });

      function setupPlayer(scope, element) {
        return new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            html5: 1,
            theme: "light",
            modesbranding: 0,
            color: "white",
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            showinfo: 1,
            controls: 1
          },
          videoId: scope.videoid,
        });
      }

      scope.$watch('videoid', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue == oldValue) {
          return;
        }
        Player.cueVideoById(scope.videoid);
      });

    }
  };
});
```

My html looks something like this,

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#">ePbKGoIGAXY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">KlyknsTJk0w</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nyc6RJEEe0U</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">zSWdZVtXT7E</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lm8p5rlrSkY</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-trailers">
    <youtube videoid="ePbKGoIGAXY"></youtube>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is click on one of the links and then change the value of `videoid` so a different youtube link is rendered.

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#">ePbKGoIGAXY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">KlyknsTJk0w</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nyc6RJEEe0U</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">zSWdZVtXT7E</a></li> <-- clicked element
    <li><a href="#">Lm8p5rlrSkY</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-trailers">
    <youtube videoid="zSWdZVtXT7E"></youtube> <-- new youtube link
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can pass videoid to the controller, and then set it the a variable. And then your directive is watching the variable. But I will prefer to another approach by using UI-Router passing variable as parameters on the link.

Comment: I'm using ui-router and templates so if you could give an example on how you would set something like that up I'm sure I can figure out my next step from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$watch` and `ng-click`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/uorogqfh/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container-info">
    <ul class="trailers">
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="videoid = 'ePbKGoIGAXY'">ePbKGoIGAXY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="videoid = 'KlyknsTJk0w'">KlyknsTJk0w</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container-trailers">
      <youtube videoid="videoid"></youtube>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive('youtube', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      videoid: "="
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $rootScope) {
      scope.$watch('videoid', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I'm running into a problem. You changed the value of `videoid` from `@` to `=` and that is causing some problems. If I change the `@` to `=` I get an error `Player is not defined`. And if I change the `=` to `@` in the ng-click I get this error `Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 8-8 [@] in expression [videoid @ 'ePbKGoIGAXY'].` any workaround?

Comment: I think you have to put the whole code inside the `scope.$watch` and use `newVal` as `videoid`